# Getting dimensions right for a single layer keras LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have some hard time to get the dimensions of a LSTM network right.

So I have the following data:

```
train_data.shape
 (25391, 3) # to be read as 25391 timesteps and 3 features

train_labels.shape
 (25391, 1) # to be read as 25391 timesteps and 1 feature
```

So I have thought my input dimension is `(1, len(train_data), train_data.shape[1])` as I plan to submit 1 batch. But I get the following error:

```
Error when checking target: expected lstm_10 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 25391, 1)
```

Here is the model code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1, # predict one feature and one timestep
               batch_input_shape=(1, len(train_data), train_data.shape[1]),
               activation='tanh',
               return_sequences=False))

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

# as 1 sample with len(train_data) time steps and train_data.shape[1] features.
model.fit(x=train_data.values.reshape(1, len(train_data), train_data.shape[1]), 
          y=train_labels.values.reshape(1, len(train_labels), train_labels.shape[1]), 
          epochs=1, 
          verbose=1, 
          validation_split=0.8, 
          validation_data=None, 
          shuffle=False)
```

How should the input dimensions look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the target (i.e. labels) shape you provide (i.e. `Error when checking target`). The output of LSTM layer in your model, which is also the output of the model, has a shape of `(None, 1)` since you are specifying to only the final output to be returned (i.e. `return_sequences=False`). In order to have the output of each timestep you need to set `return_sequences=True`. This way the output shape of LSTM layer would be `(None, num_timesteps, num_units)` which is consistent with the shape of labels array you provide.